# throw new Error('Cannot create a client without an access token');

Tags: node.js, heroku, environment-variables, access-token

I have almost deployed my app with heroku and when I try to add a campground in this case, it just gives me a blank thing. No error. This is what I get in my logs:

[[[2021-10-15T20:53:49.474030+00:00 app[web.1]: (cloudinary secret)
2021-10-15T20:53:49.474721+00:00 app[web.1]: undefined
2021-10-15T20:53:50.059515+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/lib/classes/mapi-client.js:25
2021-10-15T20:53:50.059537+00:00 app[web.1]: throw new Error('Cannot create a client without an access token');
2021-10-15T20:53:50.059538+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-10-15T20:53:50.059538+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-10-15T20:53:50.059539+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot create a client without an access token]]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOOzH.png)

I have added all of my env variables. Checked them 3 times.

Comment: you getting the status=500 in method=post path="/campgrounds". check that route out.  
 The HTTP status code 500 is a generic error response. It means that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request. This error is usually returned by the server when no other error code is suitable.

Comment: I had put in the wrong photo, I'm sorry. I updated the picture.